How to get the value of <data ..> with css selector with Scrapy?
This is the html element on the website :
<data value="5200" class="text-red-600 font-bold font-arabic  undefined"><span class="mr-1">5</span><span class="mr-1">200</span><span class="text-xs font-medium">DT</span></data>

I want to get the value "5200".
Here's what I tried :
 bike.css('data::text').get() 

bike.css('data::value').get()

bike.css('data').get()

The last one gets all the <data> element not the value.
Here's my code :
class BikespiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bikespider"
    allowed_domains = ["Domain_here"]
    start_urls = ["Link_here"]

    def parse(self, response):
        
        bikes = response.css('article.mx-0')

        for bike in bikes:
            yield {
                'name' : bike.css('h2::text').get(),
                'price' : bike.css ()
            }




            # bikes = response.css("h2::text").getall()


Do you have a specific reason for using a CSS selector, as opposed to an XPATH selector?

@BarrythePlatipus No it's just that I want to get all the content of the articles, hence, all the values of all the s . From what I know, Xpath returns only 1 element, right ?

Both XPath and CSS selectors can return all matches or the first match, the API is the same.

You could use an XPATH locator: ".//data/@value". CSS locators also use XPATH in the background, which makes them slower. If this doesn't solve your issue, then post the page URL.

@BarrythePlatipus the Answer of wRAR; bike.css('data::attr(value)').get()   worked for me. I tried to do with the XPath, (I copy paste it in response.xpath('xpath') and generally it doesn't work. Here's the link https://www.tayara.tn/fr/ads/c/Véhicules/Motos/?page=1
I tried to get the "next page" button, and I'm still searching how to do it.

bike.css('data::attr(value)').get() as documented at https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#extensions-to-css-selectors
